# What is the best way to exclude an array of entries?

Tags: entries, array

I have done a "Is featured" switch on articles which works great. I can list the latest 4 featured articles but after that I would like to list the others (Of course they may be featured too). What is the best way to exclude an array of elements when getting elements? Or is there a better solution?

### Update 1

```
{% set allArticles = craft.entries.section('articles').find() %}
{% set featuredArticles = craft.entries.section('articles').featured(1).limit(4).find() %}
{% set notFeaturedArticles = allArticles|without(featuredArticles) %}
```

This is the code and the notFeaturedArticles returns with the same entries as the allArticles.

### Update 2

```
{% set featuredArticleIds = craft.entries.section('articles').featured(1).limit(4).ids() %}
{% set featuredArticlIdsString = featuredArticleIds | join(', ') %}
{% set notFeaturedArticles = craft.entries.section('articles').id('not '~featuredArticlIdsString) %}
```

In this case only the first entry is excluded from the not featured articles.

Comment: Why do you add answers to your questions text, Hun? This is confusing.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought if I would like to add code formatting to an answer, this is the right way.

Comment: Hmm.. after reading through the answers, I see why you did this. I think it would help if you write some introduction to the code blocks, if you really want to repost the answers here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Craft documentation describes [how to exclude entries with a given value](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#parameter-value-syntax). In this case, we want a string that looks like: `'and, not id1, not id2, not id3, not id4'`

So we need a string that is all of the featured article ids separated by `, not`. First, get them as an array using [ids()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#ids):

```
{% set featuredArticleIds = craft.entries.section('articles').featured(1).limit(4).ids() %}
```

Then convert that array to a string, using [twig's join filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html):

```
{% set featuredArticleIdsString = featuredArticleIds | join(', not ') %}
```

Then, fetch all the articles, but *not* the featured ones:

```
{% set notFeaturedArticles = craft.entries.section('articles').id('and, not '~featuredArticleIdsString) %}
```

[thanks to carlcs for crucial fix]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have already tried this solution too, but the "notFeaturedArticles" filters only the first featured entry. That time I thought it can get only one entry when "not" is there. I have tried again, but with the same results: only the first entry is excluded.

Comment: @Hun there's a little mistake in Marion's answer. Use this code to compose your IDs string: `'and, not ' ~ featuredArticleIds|join(', not ')`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Marion's solution with carlcs's correction works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two ways to accomplish this:

**The [`without`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#without) filter:**

Fetch all entries and all featured entries. Then remove the latter from the first:

```twig
{% set all          = craft.entries.section('news').find() %}
{% set featured     = craft.entries.section('news').featured(1).find() %}
{% set not_featured = all|without(featured) %}
```

*Pro:* You can set the [limit](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#limit) for each type individually.
*Cons:* You need two queries (performance).

**UPDATE:**
I talked with Brad from P&T and he explained that my example is not working, because after fetching, `all` and `featured` become objects not arrays.
However it might become possible at some point in the future.

For now you would have to do it like this:

```twig
{% set allIds = craft.entries.section('news').ids() %}
{% set featuredIds = craft.entries.section('news').light('1').ids() %}
{% set notFeaturedIds = allIds|without(featuredIds) %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.id(notFeaturedIds) %}
```

---

**Sorting:**

By default all entries are sorted by date. But you could just as well [order](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#order) by "featured" first and then by [date](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#postDate).

```twig
{% set all = craft.entries.section('news').order('featured desc, postDate desc').find() %}
```

*Pros:* One query.
*Cons:* You can only set one [limit](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#limit).

Comment: I have already tried a similar solution (1st one) which didn't worked for me. I don't know why, but the query with the without() filter simply returns with all the entries.

Comment: You probably have a small mistake in your query, can you show it?

Comment: Victor your `without` solution doesn't work (see my answer), but that second solution is really nice! @HunBubu have you considered using this?

Comment: @carlcs Yes noticed this too, send a support ticket to make sure it's not a bug and will update the answer when I get an answer.

Comment: @carlcs Updated it with a working example and explanation.

Comment: @HunBubu Updated it with a working example and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The [`without`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#without) filter seems to be a bit picky with parameters. This is what did work in the end:

```
{# Get the Entry Models of the most recent feature acticles #}
{% set featuredArticles = craft.entries.section('articles').featured(1).limit(4) %}

{# Get the Entry Models of all articles without the most recent feature acticles #}
{% set notFeaturedArticles = craft.entries.section('articles').limit(null)
    |without(featuredArticles[0].title)
    |without(featuredArticles[1].title)
    |without(featuredArticles[2].title)
    |without(featuredArticles[3].title)
%}
```

Or you get the Entry Models over their IDs:

```
{# Get IDs of all the articles #}
{% set allArticlesIds = craft.entries.section('articles').ids() %}

{# Get IDs of the most recent feature acticles #}
{% set featuredArticlesIds = craft.entries.section('articles').featured(1).limit(4).ids() %}

{# Get IDs of all articles without the most recent feature acticles #}
{% set notFeaturedArticlesIds = allArticlesIds|without(featuredArticlesIds) %}

{# Get the Entry Models #}
{% set featuredArticles = craft.entries.section('articles').id(featuredArticlesIds) %}
{% set notFeaturedArticles = craft.entries.section('articles').id(notFeaturedArticlesIds) %}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Craft 3, after you get the ids you don't want (that would be an array), create your query to disregard those ids in the following way:

```
{# omitIds = array of ids you want ommited #}
{% set dontNeedIds = 'elements.id not in ('~omitIds|join(",")~')' %}
{% set news = craft.entries.section("news").where(dontNeedIds).all() %}
```