# When to use "if" or "without"?

Tags: entries, conditional, best-practice

**When is it advisable or prudent to use `without` rather than a conditional statement to exclude something, eg a set of entries, based on one parameter?**

For example, say I have real towns and fictional Towns that are listed on a related Regional page. These Towns are sorted real/fictional by a toggle field -- `0` for real, `1` for fictional.

The fictional towns are used elsewhere and should not be listed on any Regional page. **In this case, should I be using `if` (see below) or `without`?**

Here is how I am doing it right now in my Regional template:

```
{% if town.townFictional == 0 %}
    <li>{{town.link}}</li>
{% endif %}
```

This is working fine, but I came across [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/what-is-the-best-way-to-exclude-an-array-of-entries) where using `without` was suggested.

Is `without` preferred in my case, and if so how do I use it? Here is my `towns` variable:

`{% set towns = craft.entries.section('towns').relatedTo(counties) %}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your example, you should exclude the fictional towns in the initial query itself rather than filtering them out afterwards:

```
{% set towns = craft.entries.section('towns').townFictional('not 1').relatedTo(counties) %}
```

So that no towns with the Fictional Lightswitch *on* will be returned from the database at all.

You would use the `|without` filter, if you *already* had an array of items and you wanted to filter some of them out while looping over them. [This works best with arrays of simple primitives, such as an array of entry IDs, rather than whole objects](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/7178/157).

You would be more likely to use an `{% if %}` tag if you still wanted to fetch the entry, but wanted to adjust some part of your output based on a condition. So for example if you had an array of entries from different sections, and they might not all have URLs, you might decide to output a link *or* just the title:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% if entry.getUrl() %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.getUrl()">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
    {% else %}
        <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I'm trying to make my code more economical, which can be a little tough when you're teaching yourself as you go! Thanks again!

Comment: Would you be able to expound a little further and explain when `without` would be a better option?

Comment: A quick followup for anyone who may have experienced some hiccups using this method later on. Sometimes `lightswitchField(0)` won't work, it will return all entries. Using `lightswitchField('not 1')` resolved this.

See http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11911/craft-entries-and-lightswitch

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. I've updated this answer :)